# sql like operation exact word by word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a SQL table(products) like the below format

```html
<table style="height: 44px; width: 340px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">id</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">colName</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Slim</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">26</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Plus Slim</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">27</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Normal</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">28</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Plus Slim</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 17px;">29</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 17px;">wd Backup Plus Slim</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">30</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup-Plus Slim</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">38</td>
<td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">wd(Backup Plus Slim)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want exact matching rows while search **Backup Plus Slim ST2R122300** 
in product table (ie word by word ).
how I will implement it in SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Can be use `Full-Text Index` examine this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search)

Alternatively use `LIKE` `'%[^a-z]SearchValue[^a-z]%'` or `LIKE '%SearchValue%'`

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE COLNAME LIKE '%[^a-z]SearchValue[^a-z]%';
```

also why you need a database connection ? I think you solve this on client using `jQuery`

```js
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
  //split the current value of searchInput
  var data = this.value.split(" ");
  //create a jquery object of the rows
  var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
  if (this.value == "") {
    jo.show();
    return;
  }
  //hide all the rows
  jo.hide();

  //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
  jo.filter(function(i, v) {
      var $t = $(this);
      for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function() {
  this.value = "";
  $(this).css({
    "color": "black"
  });
  $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
  "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchInput" value="Type To Filter">
<br/>
<table style="height: 44px; width: 340px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>ColName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="fbody">
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">5</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Slim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">26</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Plus Slim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">27</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">28</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup Plus Slim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 17px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 17px;">29</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 17px;">wd Backup Plus Slim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">30</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">Backup-Plus Slim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 109px; height: 18px;">38</td>
      <td style="width: 217px; height: 18px;">wd(Backup Plus Slim)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks dude.i check it but what about row id 30  'Backup-Plus Slim'

Comment: extract to regex like '%SearchValue%'

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from products where colName='Backup Plus Slim ST2R122300';
```

' * ' (without quotes) - returns all columns.

products - table's name.

colName - column's name.

Comment: i know this ,but i need to return rows by exact word by word